# Missing argument in __init__()

Tags: python, python-2.x, init, zip, os.walk

I am writing a python code using os.walk module & zipfile module, which walks through give directory & creates zipfile of files which are having extension ".xlsx".

Now,whenever i am trying to run my below code its giving an TypeError **"**init**() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)".**

So far i think that python throwing this error against os.walk() & i  think i have passed correct argument to it.

```
import os,zipfile
dir_path=raw_input('Enter the root dir path\n')
with zipfile.ZipExtFile(dir_path,'w') as zf:
    for rt_dir,foldrs,files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                zf.write(os.path.join(rt_dir,file))
```

And when i run above code, it throws TypeError as bellow ..

```
>>> dir_path=raw_input('Enter the root dir path\n')
Enter the root dir path
C:\Users\KGKadam
>>> with zipfile.ZipExtFile(dir_path,'w') as zf:
...     for rt_dir,foldrs,files in os.walk(dir_path):
...         for file in files:
...             if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
...                 zf.write(os.path.join(rt_dir,file))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
>>>
```

Please help me here, i not getting where its going wrong.

Comment: `ZipExtFile` is not for manual instantiation (it is returned by `zipfile.open`), but to answer your question, the 4th argument is `zipinfo`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py#L793

Comment: Clearly error is coming from 1st line: `"<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ...` As Selcuk mentioned, ZipExtFile is a class with __init__ method. He also linked the definition so you can see exactly what you should send to ZipExtFile. Another hint you get from this link is this: `"""File-like object for reading an archive member.
       Is returned by ZipFile.open().
    """` So you might want to use a different approach to open that zip file